# Celery doesn't autodiscover tasks from all apps

Tags: django, celery, autodiscovery

I have a problem with autodiscovery tasks from all y apps.

For project

```
proj
|-- settings.py
|-- app_tasks_found
|   |-- tasks.py
|
|-- app_cant_find_tasks
|   |-- tasks.py
```

And following settings

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'proj.app_tasks_found',
    'proj.app_cant_find_tasks',
]
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'proj.settings')
from django.conf import settings
app = Celery('proj')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

After I start celery worker

```
celery worker -l info -A proj
```

It shows me only tasks from `app_tasks_found`, but not from `app_cant_find_tasks`

And of course celery raise error when I try to call task `app_cant_find_tasks.tasks.test_task.delay()`

Celery can find tasks from `app_cant_find_tasks` if I explicitly set `CELERY_IMPORTS = ("proj.app_cant_find_tasks.tasks",)`

These apps totally similar for me. I don't understand why celery can autodiscover tasks only from one app.
Question is, where should I look at to fix my problem?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and in my case the problem was I was missing the **init**.py file in one of the apps.

Comment: I spend some time debugging before realising this was the problem in my project. It's a very subtle error, and I was surprising my Django apps were otherwise working fine. As `autodiscover_tasks` seems to silently ignore all exceptions, I ended up using a trick I've had to rely before: copy-paste the output of `[n.name for n in apps.get_app_configs()]` as the first parameter to `app.autodiscover_tasks(['proj.myapp1', ....  'proj.myapp432')`, and start commenting out apps to see which app prevents importing the tasks from rest of the apps.

Comment: in my case, I just re-order my app at INSTALLED_APPS list in settings.py of django